# MOSFET as PWR/GND DPST Switch

Tags: mosfet, relay, 12v

I have started trying to replace relays in my (12V) electrical circuits with MOSFETs. I have somewhat limited experience with MOSFETs, but I think I'm starting to understand it more.

I've drawn a circuit that I believe would work as a replacement for a DPST relay. However, of the 2 poles that are switching at the output, one is power and one is ground. If these were ideal switches, I would have no reservations about this, but these being actual devices I know the response is not immediate.

1. Is my circuit design correct? I'm just getting used to using MOSFETs and could've made a mistake. The intended functionality is for the output to be +12V normally, and GND when the 12V switch is closed.
2. Do I need to worry about the potential momentary short created when the 12V switch is closed? If so, what can be done to avoid the short?

[image: DPST MOSFET Circuit]

This is the relay it is meant to replace:
[image: DPST Relay to be Replaced]

[update] The circuit initially included a P-ch depletion FET, which (pretty much) doesn't exist. This has been replaced with an N-ch depletion FET and an inverter (P-ch enhancement) in the following updated schematic.

[image: Updated DPST MOSFET Circuit]

The same questions still apply.

1. Is my circuit design correct? I'm just getting used to using MOSFETs and could've made a mistake. The intended functionality is for the output to be +12V normally, and GND when the 12V switch is closed.
2. Do I need to worry about the potential momentary short created when the 12V switch is closed? If so, what can be done to avoid the short?

Comment: Typically mosfets are drawn in an up down fashion with Vcc at the top, there is aslo a circuit editor tool built into the question (press edit and then find the circuit tool in the toolbar). It would help if you also drew the relay that you are trying to replace

Comment: The idea seems correct. But don't let the gates be floating as the MOSFETs are hi-input-impedance devices and prone to pick up noise from air which can result in an accidental turn-on. Place 1~10k across gate-source of each MOSFET to prevent this.

Comment: @RohatKılıç thanks for the reminder. I was only omitting the pull resistors for simplicity

Comment: Looks to me that when the switch is closed you'll short +12V to GND through the pair of MOSFETs connected to OUT. And also, please label your components so that they can be referred to by label when discussing a circuit...

Comment: @brhans I've added labels. M2 is a depletion FET, so is normally closed and opens when Vgs is applied. So, when S is closed, M3 and M1 close. M1 closing, in turn opens M2.

Comment: Did you have a particular part in mind? Afaik, Depletion-Mode MOSFETs are rare, and P-Channel ones are almost mythical ...

Comment: @brhans N-ch dep is not super uncommon, but I am now realizing that I'll probably have to use N-ch dep with an inverter instead of P-ch dep. However, the functionality and question remain.

Comment: @marksy95 Personally, I disagree that N-channel depletion is not super uncommon, but whatever its availability, depletion power NMOS are even rarer and a power MOSFET is probably what you want. You never did mention the current but for power switches it's pretty safe to assume you want a power MOSFET.